# Remove </p or (%3C/p) from the end of urls

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Bad theme I think was causing this.

```
/product-tag/pots/</p
```

...and I have tried many iterations from other similar questions, but the

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(<\/p>)+$/ http://www.mysite.co.uk [R=301,NC,L]
```

with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/</p /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Sadly this has not worked. I have additionally tried escaping the forward slash and the <

Comment: This is fully tested rule. It has to be your **very first rule** and then test in a new browser.